# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: price_category AFTER GIT CLONE

Tags: python-3.x, django, git, django-models, django-forms

I've been trying to solve this problem for a day now... and I can't seem to figure out why.

So after I'm working on two computer. Computer A is working fine. not throwing any error.

but Computer B after git clone keep throwing this error although I think I've set my .gitignore fine.

Things I check/tried:

1.makemigrations, migrate- its throwing the same error.

2.make sure my .gitignore is set properly.

3.Looked at all the code between two computer. Since All i did with computer B was git clone, all I had to do is checkout to the branch I commited after I git clone so all the code is the same. I really cant figure out why its throwing this error.

4. Deleted the cloned one n git clone again.

ALL to no avail.

It's making me wanna cry since I have no idea why.... tho one thing I can say for sure is the last thing I was working on on computer A was the price app.

PLEASE HELP, any clues? What can I do?

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Price, Category

choices= Category.objects.all().values_list('name', 'name')

choice_list= []

for item in choices:
    choice_list.append(item)


class PriceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Price
        fields= ('name', 'price','category')

        widgets= {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(choices=choice_list, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Category(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    #kinda like redirect. but more info corey pt10 28:00
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')  


# Create your models here.
class Price(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price= models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places=2)
    date_posted= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100, default= 'uncategorized')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Price
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import PriceForm
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    CreateView
    )

class PriceListView(ListView):
    model= Price
    

class PriceCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PriceForm
    model= Price    

    #fix the NULL author problem. Tell that the author is the current user
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import (
    PriceListView,
    PriceCreateView,
    )


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PriceListView.as_view(), name='price-list'),
    path('price-new/', views.PriceCreateView.as_view(), name='price-create'),
    ]
```

.gitignore

```
11_env/
__pycache__/
ll_env/
db.sqlite3
```

0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.6 on 2021-08-27 06:58

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion
import django.utils.timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Price',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)),
                ('date_posted', models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

0002_auto_20210828_1401.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.6 on 2021-08-28 05:01

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('price', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='price',
            name='category',
            field=models.CharField(default='uncategorized', max_length=100),
        ),
    ]
```

ERROR

```
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: price_category

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/reds/urls.py", line 36, in <module>
    path('price/', include('price.urls')),
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/price/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/price/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .forms import PriceForm
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/price/forms.py", line 9, in <module>
    for item in choices:
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 140, in __iter__
    return compiler.results_iter(tuple_expected=True, chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1130, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/seantakei/Desktop/reds/11_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 423, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: price_category
```

Comment: On the computer **B**. Try to go in the **migrations** folder of the app. Delete all migrations files but keep **0001_initial.py**. Run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` again ! And let us know the result

Comment: It's solved!!!! THANK YOU!!!! @Rvector